# setInterval does not apply state changes until timeout ends

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I'm trying to fetch data from a service and when any of states below changed, i want to clear the interval and keep going with new states

Tried this code but it didnt help.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if(autoRefresh) {
            let intervalCall = setInterval(getTaskElements,6000);
            return () => {
                // clean up
                clearInterval(intervalCall);
            };
        }
    }, [changes, paging, taskParams, sorting, language,autoRefresh]);
```

Comment: We really need more info here than just your `useEffect`,  for best answers try an knock up a snippet demonstrating the issue..

Comment: fundementelly same, when you change the state below with the button, it does not effect upper state in interval immediately. https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-bird-sneemd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @alperyolcu what is a closure? and why do `const`s not change their value? `incremetVal` is a closure over a **constant** value, then you add `+1` and pass the result to `setMyVal`; over and over and over again. The summary of your problem/code: `const val = 2; setInterval(() => setState(val+1), 5000);`

Comment: well i would like to trigger state change event of my main state in useEffect when useEffect deps changes. In summary i want to terminate my setinterval before its time parameter reached given value when any state change happen in useeffect deps, and create new interval with new values immediately.